# Can I add "A" tag into mediawiki wikitext permitted list?

Tags: wordpress, mediawiki

Our company hosts a wiki website for years with WordPress, and now we decide to migrate it to MediaWiki.

However, all articles in our wiki are not written in wikitext, but raw HTML code, and there are lots of `<a href...>Link</a>` which MediaWiki will convert to `&lt;a href...&gt;Link&lt;/a&gt;`. We have hundreds of thousands articles, so I don't think it's a good idea to convert those old articles to wikitext.

I have tried to set `$wgRawHtml = true` and add `<html>` and `</html>` around the code, however, TOC is broken then (also, it's not safe to use in production).

I also have tested some extensions, for example, https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:HTML_Tags and https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:AllowAnchorTags, but both of them don't support `<a href=...` itself.

Is there any better solution to match my case? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Secure_HTML. It definitely supports `<a href=...` but you would need to build a snippet for every HTML block of your page.
If you don't have wiki markup within your wikitext you could wrap the whole wikitext into a snippet - so you would need only one snippet per page.

Another solution is to replace all `<a href=...` with the very helpful https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Replace_Text
It should work with those 3 operations:

- Replace `<a href="` with `[`
- Replace `">` (or `" target="_blank">`) with
- Replace `</a>"` with `]`